# Multithreaded program exercise

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm currently working on a multithreaded program to represent a TA with n students. When students arrive, they have to sit in the hallway on a chair (there are 3 chairs available + 1 chair in the TA office). If there are no more chairs then, they have to go back home and wait.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex; /* mutex lock */
sem_t studentSem;
sem_t taSem;

int chairs = 1;

void *student(void *param);
void *ta(void *param);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  if(argc!=2){
    fprintf(stderr, "Un nombre d'etudiant est requis en paramètre\n");
    return -1;
  }

  if(atoi(argv[1])<0){
      fprintf(stderr, "Un nombre d'etudiant >= 0 est requis\n");
      return -1;
  }else{
    int numStudents = atoi(argv[1]);
    int numThreads = numStudents + 1; /* n etudiant + 1 TA */

    pthread_t tid[numThreads]; /* thread ID */
    pthread_attr_t attr; /* thread attributes */

    sem_init(&studentSem, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&taSem, 0, 0); /* 0 car TA attend etudiant */

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

    int i = 0;
    pthread_create(&tid[i], &attr, ta, NULL); /*creer le TA*/

    for (i = 1; i < numThreads; i++){
      pthread_create(&tid[i], &attr, student, (void*)i); /*creer etudiant*/
    }

    for (i = 0; i < numThreads; i++){
      pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    }
  }
  return 0;

} /*fin du main*/

void *ta (void *param){ /*le thread pour TA*/
  while(ta){
    sem_post(&studentSem);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    chairs--;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    printf("helping students\n");
    sleep(rand()%(1+3));
    sem_wait(&taSem);
  }
}

void *student(void *param){
  int *t;
  t = (int *)param;

  while(student){
    if(chairs < 4){
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);         /* protects chairs */
      chairs++;                           /* incrementer chairs car etudiant prend cette chaise */
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);       /* releases mutex lock */
      printf("%i is sitting down\n", t);
      sem_post(&taSem);                   /* etudiant signal le TA pour demander de l'aide */
      sem_wait(&studentSem);              /* etudiant attend jusqua temps que TA l'aide et peut ensuite partir */
    } else {  /* no chairs available, so the student "goes home" */
      printf("%i is going home\n", t);
      sleep(rand()%(1+5)); /* sleeps a random amount of time */
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is I can't get it to work properly. When I run the program using "sleepingTA 5" on UNIX, it gives me the following result:

```
1 is sitting down
1 is sitting down
1 is sitting down
1 is sitting down
2 is sitting down
3 is going home
4 is going home
5 is going home
5 is going home 
1 is going home
1 is sitting down
...
```

The loop is always working infinitely. I don't know how to change it so, after being helped, the student leaves... (not like #1 who comes back).

Also, I need the student to sit only once, not many times in a row (like 1) and I need the student to go home once, not many times in a row (like 5)...

Comment: What in your code do you think stops the same student from sitting down over and over?

Comment: Nothing yet... I tried saying sem_post(&studentSem) to release it, but didn't work!

Comment: Please what is a "*TA*"? Terminal Adapter?-)

Answer (score 1):

The code fully misses to implement any error checking. If it would test the outcome of relevant library calls, you would have noticed that (at least) all the `pthread_mutex*()` calls fail, because the mutex variable passed in never got initialized.

The easiest way to fix this is to use an initialiser like this:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

Alternatively the code could initialise the mutex on startup:

```
#include <errno.h> /* for errno */

...

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (0 != (errno = pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL)))
  {
    perror("pthread_mutex_init() failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the whole answer, but...:

You're performing a check on the number of chairs before entering the critical section.

This means that by the time you enter the `lock`, the data in `chairs` might no longer be valid.

```
  while(student){
    if(chairs < 4){
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);         /* protects chairs */
      chairs++;                           /* incrementer chairs car etudiant prend cette chaise */
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);       /* releases mutex lock */
      printf("%i is sitting down\n", t);
      sem_post(&taSem);                   /* etudiant signal le TA pour demander de l'aide */
      sem_wait(&studentSem);              /* etudiant attend jusqua temps que TA l'aide et peut ensuite partir */
    } else {  /* no chairs available, so the student "goes home" */
      printf("%i is going home\n", t);
      sleep(rand()%(1+5)); /* sleeps a random amount of time */
    }
```

I think you need to enter the lock before the if statement. Also, you need to exit the thread (or set `student` to 0) when you're done.

```
  while(student){
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);         /* protects chairs */
    if(chairs < 4){
      chairs++;                           /* incrementer chairs car etudiant prend cette chaise */
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);       /* releases mutex lock */
      printf("%i is sitting down\n", t);
      sem_post(&taSem);                   /* etudiant signal le TA pour demander de l'aide */
      sem_wait(&studentSem);              /* etudiant attend jusqua temps que TA l'aide et peut ensuite partir */
      pthread_exit(0);              /* finish when you're done */

    } else {  /* no chairs available, so the student "goes home" */
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);       /* releases mutex lock */
      printf("%i is going home\n", t);
      sleep(rand()%(1+5)); /* sleeps a random amount of time */
    }
```

Another thing is that the first `i` == 0... you might want to use `i+1` to avoid the `0` value as the student identifier:

```
 pthread_create(&tid[i], &attr, student, (void*)(i+1));
```

P.S.

You might want to use a different `mutex` for the TA, so sitting in the chair could be `pthread_mutex_lock(&TA_lock);`, so the students go to the TA the moment the TA is available...

...but, the issue with this approach is that the line is undefined (the students waiting aren't chosen at a specific order)... you might want to use an array/bin-tree for the chairs and have the TA handle the queue and the students with another loop, protecting the bin-tree/array with the mutex.

Answer (score -1):

What is this line doing while(student){ in  void *student(void *param) ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer. To request additional info please leave a comment.

Comment: Ummm. Tried doing that. Doesn't let me comment since I don't have enough reputation. Btw, TA is Teaching Assistant.